# Постановка тире

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Как лучше написать?

1. Иногда думалось: «Что первично – то, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?»
2. Иногда думалось: «Что первично? То, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?»

Или здесь вообще кавычки не нужны?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант лучше, т.к. далее следует пояснение. Раздробив предложение, получится ненужная подчеркивание, логическое выделение. Невысказанные мысли автора берутся в кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Я за этот вариант:

Что первично? То, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?

или за двоеточние:

Что первично (далее идет пояснение): то, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?

Answer (score 0):

А я бы после "что первично" поставил двоеточие.

Comment: Вы правы, Виктор, можно и двоеточие. Но тире служит интонационным отделением главной части от следующей за ней придаточной. Ср.напр: Вы спросите - зачем я пошел на это?( См.у Розенталя. Стр. 268).  К тому же двоеточие уже есть.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Я бы оставила вариант: Иногда думалось: «Что первично? То, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?»

Только это предложение выразительно, так как сразу выражена вопросительная интонация. И только оно является читаемым с точки зрения интонации.

Вариант 2. Иногда думалось: «Что первично – то, что он выглядит так молодо, не на свой возраст, или то, что душа сохраняет молодой задор и энергию?»

Если рассматривать только прямую речь, то там надо ставить двоеточие (вопросительное местоимение "ЧТО" требует объяснительного разъяснения и соответствующей предупредительной паузы).

Если это "слова автора + прямая речь", то в устной речи это две паузы подряд (после слов автора и после "что первично"), а также вопросительная интонация в самом конце сообщения (повышение голоса), что с трудом произносится и также с трудом воспринимается.